# How to initialize a TypeORM Repository based on a Generic Type "T"?

Tags: typescript, generics, typeorm

I would like to Initiate a TypeORM Repository based on a Generic Type.

for instance:

```
import { Connection, Repository } from 'typeorm';

export class GenericService<T> {
    private repository: Repository<T>;

    constructor(connection: Connection) {
        this.repository = connection.getRepository(T);
        // 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
    }

    public async list(): Promise<T[]> {
        return await this.repository.find();
    }

}
```

But I was not able to pass Generic Type to the ORM Repository Factory.

> 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693

How can I create this generic service based on the Generic Type?

PS. I did exactly this with C# and works like a charm. it saves me a lot of time

Comment: You need to understand that TypeScript is not C#. TypeScripts eventually get transpiled into JavaScripts, and all the generics, types etc. are only there for the moment to help you making sure that your code is sound. Once transpiled, all those things are gone and you don't see them anywhere in the resulting JavaScript. So there is no `T`, and thus of course you cannot use it as a parameter. A workaround is provided by Yeysides below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use types as values in Typescript, so you'll need to use the generic to type check the value instead:

```
import { Connection, Repository } from 'typeorm';
    
export class GenericService<T> {
   private repository: Repository<T>;
    
   constructor(connection: Connection, repo: T) {
      this.repository: T = connection.getRepository(repo);
   }
    
   public async list(): Promise<T[]> {
      return await this.repository.find();
   }
    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Usually I use`EntityTarget` type to avoid this error. The code looks like:

```js
import { Connection, Repository, EntityTarget } from 'typeorm';

export class GenericService<T> {
   private repository: Repository<T>;

   constructor(connection: Connection, repo: EntityTarget<T>) {
      this.repository = connection.getRepository<T>(repo);
   }

   public async list(): Promise<T[]> {
      return await this.repository.find();
   }

}
```

Comment: This is the best solution on current TypeORM version.

Answer (score 1):

**2023 Update**

(**typeorm `^0.3.17`, typescript `5.1.3`**)

According to several issues published in typeorm repository ([5152](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5152), [9331](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9331)) almost all previous solutions or it's parts are deprecated (for example, **`Connection`**) or even no longer work due to types evolution.

Another approach would be passing `Entity` itself as generic `<T>`:

```
export class GenericService<T extends EntityTarget<ObjectLiteral>> {
    private entityManager: EntityManager;
    private repository: Repository<ObjectLiteral>;

    constructor(entity: T) {
        this.repository = this.entityManager.getRepository(entity);
    }

    public async list() {
        return await this.repository.find();
    }
}
```

Note that with this sample `list()` return type would be `Promise<ObjectLiteral[]>`, not `Promise<T[]>`.